# How add material-ui/Button in codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

I make https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-golick-p4etx?file=/src/components/LinkBtn.js

if I add material-ui and @svelte-material-ui/button but its not help.

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'material-ui/Button' relative to '/src/components/LinkBtn.js'
```

What for codesandbox Dependencies need add?

Comment: Voting to close as typo, you aren't referencing material-ui correctly, use `import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'` in LinkBtn.js and `import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline'` in App.js.

Comment: It works. Very grateful! Now the application has started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is added under [`@material-ui/core`](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/)

`import {Button} from '@material-ui/core'`

`import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'`

Answer (score 0):

I used https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js and now no any 
Error.

Answer (score 0):

To use Material-UI (MUI) in Code Sandbox, you need to first add the required dependency as follows:
1.@emotion/react
2.@emotion/styled
3.@mui/icon-material
4.@mui/material